# Configuring mongodb 3.0 for memory limit

Tags: mongodb, memory-management, wiredtiger

Does any one know how to limit memory in mongodb 3.0. I already know that it is not possible in mongodb 2.x version. But how to do that in 3.0 (WiredTiger).

Mongodb is eating all the cache in my system.

Answer (score 0):

I think MongoDB's approach is: Take all there is.

So if you don't want to go to the full blown container route, your best bet is probably [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) if you're on Linux. Incidentally, Percona has written a blog post about it this week: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/07/01/using-cgroups-to-limit-mysql-and-mongodb-memory-usage/